# extraer el valor de un elemento en un array con javascript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo el siguiente array

```
Array
(
    [inv_id] => 193
    [inv_prefix] => PREF
    [inv_number] => 192
    [inv_quotationNumber] => 0
    [inv_date] => 2018-04-09
    [inv_dateDue] => 2018-04-09
    [inv_empId] => 2
    [inv_cntId] => 304
    [inv_storage] => 1
    [inv_total] => 3200.00
    [inv_balance] => 3196.80
)
```

Como puedo obtener el valor del elemento `[inv_total]` con javascript?

Comment: eso tiene pinta de ser un array object, pero un apregunta ¿Ese erra lo formas tu?

Comment: lo obtengo de una consulta mysql  `$data = $stmt_doc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: y así te llega cuando le haces echo?

Comment: No, asi se ve en `console.log`, es una consulta de un solo registro

Comment: por que no al enviarlo lo envias como json mejor

Comment: Ese `array` es de qué lenguaje?

Comment: php Kleith aparece ahi en el comentario

Comment: No, no aparece pero bueno, gracias.

Comment: Lo envio desde php y lo recive una funcion javascript

Comment: lo que pasa es que ese array no lo lee javascript solo lo puedes leer en php y si lo retornas deberias hacerle un json_encode para retornarlo

Comment: si quieres solo obtener el `[inv_total]` solo haz lo siguiente `$data['inv_total']` y despues lo retornas.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo envías por PHP, lo que tenés que hacer es formatearlo a un [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) con el método de [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php), luego de lado de javascript lo obtienes con, supongamos que se llama `data`, `data.inv_total`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$array = array('inv_total' => 3200.00);
json_encode($array);
```

Luego en javascript:

```
// acá iría tu ajax o fetch
var data = obtenerDatoDePHP();

console.log(data.inv_total);
```

Comment: con `json_encode` llega asi `{"inv_id":463,"inv_prefix":"PREF","inv_number":460,"inv_quotationNumber":0,"inv_date":"2018-04-13","inv_dateDue":"2018-04-13","inv_empId":1,"inv_payment":"30 Dias","inv_cntId":304,"inv_costCenter":"","inv_storage":1,"inv_comment":"","inv_pucId":null,"inv_puc":null,"inv_valTip":"0.00","inv_subTotal":"0.00","inv_percDiscount":"0.00","inv_valDiscount":"0.00","inv_taxBase":"0.00","inv_tax":"0.00","inv_taxAdicional1":"0.00","inv_taxAdicional2":"0.00","inv_valRF":"0.00","inv_total":"0.00"}`

Comment: Perfecto! Ese resultado lo pasas a una variable, pongamosle `data`, y luego imprimes `data.inv_total`. Esto, obviamente, del lado de javascript.

Comment: `$("#rdt_documentId").change(function () {
        $.get("views/adm_receipt_doc.php", "inv_id=" + $("#rdt_documentId").val(), function (data) {
            var total = data();
            console.log(total.invTotal);
        });
    });
`
esto me da error

Comment: @JuanCarlos lo quieres recorrer? o solo el valor de inv_total

Comment: [al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76681/json-recorrer) @JuanCarlos

Comment: Necesito el valor de varios elementos no consecutivos

Comment: En vez de `var total = data();` hacé `var total = data;`.